# Cannot find MySQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

MySQL gives me syntax error for a simple query but I don't see any error. If you guys find any please help.

```
insert into cast(sid,celeb_id,type,name,prior)
  values(30,1,1,'James Keziah Delaney',2)
```

It gives sql syntax error near `cast`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main cause of this error is that there is a function [Cast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)  in mysql.

It look like to call the `cast()` function.

You can choose one of the solutions to solve it.

1. add ` to contain cast table name

look like this.

```
insert into `cast`(sid,celeb_id,type,name,prior) values(30,1,1,'James Keziah Delaney',2)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbb270)

2. add a space between `cast` and `(` let mysql know you did't want to execute [Cast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)  method.  thank for @Barmar remind.

**Note:**

I would suggest you don't give the table name from keyword or function name.

Comment: It's not listed on the reserved words page you linked to.

Comment: You can also just put a space between `cast` and `(`. Then it doesn't look like a function call.

Comment: Correct on the reserved work @Barmar but is is on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/func-op-summary-ref.html as a function

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert into cast(). It requires a list of column names.

Comment: Based on the syntax, it looks like the table name is `cast`.

Comment: Not a great choice for a table name. 8-)